# Insert null/empty value in sql datetime column by default

Tags: sql

How do I create a table in SQL server with the default DateTime as empty, not `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` that I get?

I mean, if there is no value inserted, the default value should be null, empty, etc.

Comment: `if there is no value inserted, the default value should be null,empty` Then why not make it Nullable, and insert `NULL`?

Comment: I HAVE ALLOWED NULL VARIABLES THOUGH..

Comment: Can you show a sample `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> if there is no value inserted, the default value should be null,empty

In the table definition, make this `datetime` column allows null, be not defining `NOT NULL`:

```
...
DateTimeColumn DateTime,
...
```

> I HAVE ALLOWED NULL VARIABLES THOUGH.

Then , just insert `NULL` in this column:

```
INSERT INTO Table(name, datetimeColumn, ...)
VALUES('foo bar', NULL, ..);
```

Or, you can make use of the [DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) constaints:

```
...
DateTimeColumn DateTime DEFAULT NULL,
...
```

Then you can ignore it completely in the `INSERT` statement and it will be inserted withe the `NULL` value:

```
INSERT INTO Table(name, ...)
VALUES('foo bar', ..);
```

Comment: The issue is, that if the input is empty, then it shouldn't put '1900-0-0-0 etc' but NULL, and i shouldn't have to put all those conditions then

Comment: @OziOz See my edit. Make it `DEFAULT NULL` and  igonre it in the insert list, other wise if you didn't used `DEFAULT NULL`, make it nullable and insert null in that column

Comment: I'm sorry Mahmud i don't understand you that well :(
Where do i put this?
should i create a New Query for this?
DateTimeColumn DateTime DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: @OziOz If this datetime fild is defined as `DateTimeColumn DateTime DEFAULT NULL`, just ignore it in the insert columns' list and it will be inserted with `NULL` value.

Comment: Aha... ok, i got it :)
Thanks!

Comment: @OziOz - You're welcome. Sorry if my answers confused you, but I always try to simplify it.

Comment: what should I do if I want to import a time variable which contains blank records from a flat file to sql server

Answer (score 2):

Even if your column is nullable, inserting an empty string will set the value to 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. Make you insert real nulls not strings, then the db will store a null.

Answer (score 0):

1. define it like `your_field DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL`
2. dont insert a blank string, insert a NULL `INSERT INTO x(your_field)VALUES(NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Ozi, when you create a new datetime object as in
datetime foo = new datetime();
foo is constructed with the time datetime.minvalue()
in building a parameterized query, you could check to see if the values entered are equal to datetime.minvalue()

-Just a side thought. seems you have things working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue this morning. It appears that for a DATE or DATETIME field, an empty value cannot be inserted. I got around this by first checking for an empty value  (mydate = "") and if it was empty setting mydate = "NULL" before insert.

The DATE and DATETIME fields don't behave in the same way as VARCHAR fields.

Comment: _"DATE and DATETIME fields don't behave in the same way as VARCHAR"_ - that's because an empty, non-null string (`""`) is a valid string, but it's not possible to construct a valid, empty, non-null date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
string Log_In_Val = (Convert.ToString(attenObj.Log_In) == "" ? "Null" + "," : "'" + Convert.ToString(attenObj.Log_In) + "',");
```