# How to insert null value in datetime column of mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a table in which a column levdat is of DateTime datatype. its value is inserted by a textbox. sometimes it can be null. I want whenever textbox is empty null is inserted into database column. but it is inserting **0001-01-01 00:00:00**. my code is

```
string date3=txt_lev_dat.Text;
if (date3 != "")
{
    if ((!DateTime.TryParse(date3, out datetime)) && (date3 != ""))
    {
        lbl_lev_war.Text = "Incorrect Date";
        lbl_lev_war.ToolTip = "Please Enter Correct Date";
    }
    else
    {
        objprp.p_tchlevdat = Convert.ToDateTime(date3);
    }
}
```

I tried to enter DBnull.value. but it gives me error. Thanks in advance.
My store procedure is

```
DELIMITER $$

 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db_school_management`.`ins_tch`$$

       CREATE PROCEDURE `db_school_management`.`ins_tch`(citycod INT,_statecod INT,_tchfstnam       VARCHAR(50),_tchlstnam VARCHAR(50),_tchfatnam VARCHAR(50),
    _tchmotnam VARCHAR(50),_tchdob DATETIME,_tchgen VARCHAR(5),_tchadd VARCHAR(200),_tchmob VARCHAR(20),_tchphn VARCHAR(20),_tchzipcod VARCHAR(10),
    _tchedu VARCHAR(50),_tchsal INT,_tcheml VARCHAR(50),_tchusrnam VARCHAR(50),_tchpwd VARCHAR(50),_tchjoindat DATETIME,_tchpic VARCHAR(50),_tchlevdat DATETIME,_flag VARCHAR(5))
        BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbteacher(citycod,statecod,tchfstnam,tchlstnam,tchfatnam,tchmotnam,tchdob,tchgen,tchadd,tchmob,tchphn,tchzipcod,tchedu,tchsal,
    tcheml,tchusrnam,tchpwd,tchjoindat,tchpic,tchlevdat,flag) VALUES(_citycod,_statecod,_tchfstnam,_tchlstnam,_tchfatnam,_tchmotnam,_tchdob,_tchgen,
    _tchadd,_tchmob,_tchphn,_tchzipcod,_tchedu,_tchsal,_tcheml,_tchusrnam,_tchpwd,_tchjoindat,_tchpic,_tchlevdat,_flag);
        END
```

Comment: "but it gives me error" - which error would that be?

Comment: does the column accept `Null` value in MySQL?

Comment: @MitchWheat Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Yes column accept Null value .

Comment: follow this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default

Comment: @downvoter can you explain why this question is off topic. some guys here sit only to downvote questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use ISNULL Property in MySQL

## [ISNULL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,198593)

Like this

```
ISNULL(levdat,'')
```

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$

 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db_school_management`.`ins_tch`$$

 CREATE PROCEDURE `db_school_management`.`ins_tch`
     (citycod INT,_statecod INT,_tchfstnam       VARCHAR(50),_tchlstnam VARCHAR(50),_tchfatnam   VARCHAR(50),
    _tchmotnam VARCHAR(50),_tchdob DATETIME,_tchgen VARCHAR(5),_tchadd VARCHAR(200),_tchmob VARCHAR(20),_tchphn VARCHAR(20),_tchzipcod VARCHAR(10),
    _tchedu VARCHAR(50),_tchsal INT,_tcheml VARCHAR(50),_tchusrnam VARCHAR(50),_tchpwd VARCHAR(50),_tchjoindat DATETIME,_tchpic VARCHAR(50),_tchlevdat DATETIME,_flag VARCHAR(5))
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbteacher(citycod,statecod,tchfstnam,tchlstnam,tchfatnam,tchmotnam,tchdob,tchgen,tchadd,tchmob,tchphn,tchzipcod,tchedu,tchsal,
    tcheml,tchusrnam,tchpwd,tchjoindat,tchpic,tchlevdat,flag) VALUES(_citycod,_statecod,_tchfstnam,_tchlstnam,_tchfatnam,_tchmotnam,ISNULL(_tchdob,''),_tchgen,        _tchadd,_tchmob,_tchphn,_tchzipcod,_tchedu,_tchsal,_tcheml,_tchusrnam,_tchpwd,_tchjoindat,_tchpic,ISNULL(_tchlevdat,''),_flag);
 END
```

Comment: thanks for answering vignesh, but i have to do it from c#. i am using store procedureto insert the value.

Comment: No problem add that line in  store procedure.. Mark useful if it helped you

Comment: okey, Vignesh I'll try it

Comment: else post your stored proc. Ill give you suggestion

Comment: It is giving me error 1582 mysql

Comment: Can you post your stored proc

Comment: OP seems expecting a `null` go into db field, when text box is empty. *... I want whenever textbox is empty null is inserted into database column. but it is inserting 0001-01-01 00:00:00. ...*

Comment: ya ISNULL propery will do that only

Comment: Error Code : 1582
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: [ISNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) tests if the passed expression is NULL. What you need is [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), or COALESCE, as `xyld` has mentioned.