# Can Date attribute allow null value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I have created a Model file for my MVC project that contains the following:

```
Public Class Player

    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property GoesBy As String
    Public Property Birthdate As Date

End Class
```

I didn't mark the `Birthdate` field as a Required field, but it won't accept nulls.  How can I add a validation or something else to allow for nulls?  Or is that not possible and I have to just insert `1900-01-01` or something similar?

Comment: use Public Property Birthdate as  Nullable(Of Date)

Comment: Umm... how about `Nullable(Of Date)`. Did you even bother to look at any documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert null/empty value in sql datetime column by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default)

Comment: @ChrisPratt, yes I did, my apologies on not finding the answer. Thanks for providing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make your property `Public Property Birthdate As Date` as `nullable` like shown below:

```
Public Property Birthdate As Nullable(Of Date)
```

and just make your database field which accepts Birthdate as nullable so that it can accept null values also.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I believe it would work; however, I can't get the add-migration to pick it up just yet so I'm investigating how to correct that.