# Insert from tableA into tableB where some datetime values are null

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, null, insert-into

[tableB] was created from scripting [tableA], but with columns rearranged, which is the primary reason for this task.
I now want to INSERT INTO [tableB] SELECT (column list) FROM [tableA].
[tableA] has several NULL values in a datetime2(0) column.
I get the following error when running the INSERT:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Most likely this has been answered before, but I cannot seem to word my searches in a way that finds the answer.  This site has been very helpful to me.  I am hopeful for a simple solution, and appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using [CONVERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change the data type.

Comment: I think answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default