# Stop a Null value date inserting in the table when the textbox value is null using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to stop the default value date "01/01/1900"to be entered in the table when the value of the textbox is null.I don't need validation on the form null textbox is ok
Thanks

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager
       .ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
{
   con.Open();

   using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into ClinicalFollowUp  (MBID, Diagnosis, 
          DateLastSeen, DateofDeath ) values(@MBID, Upper(@Diagnosis), 
          Convert (date, @DateLastSeen , 103), Convert (date, @DODeath, 103);", con))
   {
      sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", txtMBID1.Text);
      sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Diagnosis", txtDiagnosis.Text);

      // Date  Textbox
      sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateLastSeen", txtDateLastSeen.Text);

      // Date  Textbox
      sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DODeath", txtDateDeath.Text);
   }
   con.close();
}
```

Comment: `.Text` won't be null.

Comment: where is your `ExecuteNonQuery` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert null/empty value in sql datetime column by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default)

Comment: You should really avoid to pass strings to a datatable that expects dates. Use the appropriate datatype and avoid AddWithValue in particular with dates.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I forgot to add  sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should send the parameters in your command using

   - The correct data type (NOT as string and do not convert them in Sql Server!)
   - Specify the data type of the parameter
   - Specify the length of parameter data types where appropriate. I guessed at your string lengths in the schema, update it accordingly.
2. Execute the conversion as early as possible in your call stack. Ideally you have a control that is a datetime picker, maybe this can do the conversion for you OR if its a web api then let the serializer deserialize the request to the approriate types.

   const string sqlStatement = @"Insert into ClinicalFollowUp  (MBID,  Diagnosis,   DateLastSeen,  DateofDeath ) 
     VALUES(@MBID, @Diagnosis , @DateLastSeen, @DODeath);"

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
   using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand( , con))
   {
       con.Open();
       sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MBID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100){Value = txtMBID1.Text});
       sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Diagnosis", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000){Value = txtDiagnosis.Text.ToUpper()});

   ```
   // Date  Textbox
   sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateLastSeen", SqlDbType.DateTime){Value = getSqlDate(txtDateLastSeen.Text)});

   // Date  Textbox
   sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DODeath", SqlDbType.DateTime){Value = getSqlDate(txtDateDeath.Text)});


   sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
   ```

   }

   // TO DO - validate culture information
   public static object getSqlDate(string dateTime)
   {
       DateTime dt;
       return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime) && DateTime.TryParse(dateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
           ? (object) dt
           : (object) System.DBNull.Value;
   }

Comment: Thanks Mate Worked fine

Comment: Hi Igor  the date is inserted in the table with this format Dec  3 2017 12:00AM just want to know how can I change the input format to dd/MM/yyyy In my previous code I was using Convert to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @EricMbiada - dates do not have a format, they are a binary representation of a point in time (in reality ticks from a specific point in time). The only time you need to be aware of the DateTime format is when you parse it from `string` to `dateTime` in c#. Other than that you pass a `DateTime` to the query AND your table column types should also be of `DateTime` type.

Comment: @EricMbiada - so if `DateTime.TryParse` does not work due to a format then try `DateTime.TryParseExact` and add the format `dd/MM/yyyy` (if that is what is coming in).

Comment: @EricMbiada - one more note. Whenever you want to present a date in the presentation layer (ie. the UI) you can use `ToString` and pass a formatter as parameter. Example: `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd yy");`

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way, personally.

```
static public object ToDbNullableDate(this string s)
{
    DateTime d;
    var ok = DateTime.TryParse(s, out d);
    return ok ? d : DbNull.Value;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateLastSeen", txtDateLastSeen.Text.ToDbNullableDate());
```

Comment: when I added the code I am having this error The name 'DbNull' does not exist in the current context any suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you are `using System`

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDateLastSeen.Text)
{
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateLastSeen", DbNull.Value);
}
else
{
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateLastSeen", txtDateLastSeen.Text);
}
```

EDIT: IsNullOrWhiteSpace, as suggested, is a bit simpler.

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Comment: `Convert ( date, @DateLastSeen ,103) , Convert ( date, @DODeath, 103);` would still cast it to the default 01/01/1901

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for suggestion. I mostly use `IsNullOrEmpty`, out of habit I suppose :)