# How to insert NULL into the DATETIME coulmn instead 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am new to SQL Server here I am trying to insert date into the column which has `DATETIME` as datatype .

When I pass a datetime to the stored procedure from API it insert the values which I have passed. But If I pass an empty string `" "`, it inserts a default value of `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. But I want to insert `NULL` if the data is  `" "`.

I googled a lot but I can't find a solution for this .

```
@DATEVAL1 DATETIME = '',
@DATEVAL1 DATETIME = ''

INSERT INTO TABLE (mDate1, mDate2)
VALUES (@DATEVAL1, @DATEVAL2);
```

This is the code I have in my stored procedure.

Comment: Make the field `nullable`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert null/empty value in sql datetime column by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934621/insert-null-empty-value-in-sql-datetime-column-by-default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set a datetime variable to an empty string an implicit conversion happens. And an empty string converts implicitly to 1900-01-01. Either just declare the variable and don't assign them a value or explicitly set them to NULL.

```
@DATEVAL1 DATETIME,
@DATEVAL2 DATETIME = NULL
```

Or you could use NULLIF. Since you are receiving these values from an API you would most likely have to use NULLIF. Otherwise a change to the API call would be required to send in a NULL instead of an empty string.

```
Values( NULLIF(@DATEVAL1, '')
```

Comment: You cant control `@DATEVAL` if came from an API call. So I suggest you go with `NULLIF`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza excellent point. I somehow glossed over that these were the values being received. Absolutely need to use NULLIF to make this work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Dates and strings are not the same thing.  For some reason, SQL Server converts an empty string into the date value `'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` rather than generating an error.

My primary advice is to not use empty strings for dates.  Instead, just use `NULL`:

```
DECLARE @DATEVAL1 DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @DATEVAL1 DATETIME = NULL;

INSERT INTO TABLE (mDate1, mDate2)
    VALUES (@DATEVAL1, @DATEVAL2);
```

If for some reason you have to use empty strings, then you can use a trigger to convert the 1900 value to `NULL` or use `NULLIF()` in the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (mDate1, mDate2)
    VALUES (NULLIF(@DATEVAL1, ''), NULLIF(@DATEVAL2, ''));
```

Comment: The problem is if this is an API function receiving `DATETIME` others can call it using `''` and the OP will get `1900-01-01` anyway, isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . If that is addressed to me, I don't understand the question.  `NULLIF()` solves the problem regardless of whether the code is in a stored procedure or not.  SQL Server causes the problem by allowing an empty string to be converted to an arbitrary date.

Answer (score 0):

I will go on a different direction as the other two answers.

My guess is you have an APP with some dropdown combos or some text fields. Your APP call your API and then you send those values to the stored procedure. Sometimes the app send empty string and when you send those to the stored procedure are converted to `1900-01-01`.

So if you have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertDate 
    @DATEVAL1 DATETIME, @DATEVAL1 DATETIME
AS
    INSERT INTO TABLE (mDate1, mDate2) 
    VALUES (@DATEVAL1, @DATEVAL2);
GO
```

In this case if you send `''` to the stored procedure you will get `1900-01-01` at the moment the parameters are created because an implicit conversion occurs so `NULLIF()` won't work here.

You can add some `IF ()` logic to the stored procedure to convert any `1900-01-01` to `NULL` before run the `INSERT`

Or you can add the logic to your API converting any `''` to `NULL` before calling the stored procedure.

Comment: IFNULL() doesn't work anywhere, at least in SQL Server as it is not a built in function name.  You are probably confusing NULLIF() and ISNULL(); the former substitutes a null value if the first argument equals the second argument, the latter substitutes the second argument for the first argument when the first argument is NULL.  But as you say, the conversion will have already happened when a blank string is passes into a parameter of a specified datatype in a stored procedure.  Best thing would be to have the app test and perform business logic against the user input.

Comment: @ChadEstes You are right I mean `NULLIF()` as the other answers suggest. And yes validate the input before send to the stored procedure